# Deploy war file to jetty using jenkins

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins, jetty

I deployed the war file to tomcat using jenkins as a post-build action

```
WAR/EAR files=**/demo.war
Context path=application
Container=tomcat 7

Manager user name=admin
Manager password=admin
Tomcat URL=https://localhost:8080/
```

How to deploy a war file to **jetty** instead of tomcat using **jenkins**. The project is a maven project which does not have any plugin for jetty.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is the following:

**1.** Add to pluguns of pom.xml next lines

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.1.v20140108</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                <stopKey>stopKey</stopKey>
                <stopWait>20</stopWait>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**2.** Change goals to

mvn jetty:stop jetty:run-forked

If you cannot change pom.xml then you can create separate pom.xml (on other folder). And run the same tasks with this pom.xml. Post Steps > Invoke top-level maven target > advavanced